# How to apply a for-loop and t-test to a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, statistics

I'm trying to apply a for-loop to a dataframe in R, using it to take the row number, which will be used in a t-test, along with specified column indices.
When I run the code I currently have, it only takes the last value specified in the for-loop. **How do I fix this?** (sorry I'm a complete novice)

This is my code:
x represents the dataset

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    test<- t.test(x[i, 1:5], x[i, 6:10])
    return(test$p.value)
  }
```

I want it to run a t-test on every row, using i (as the row number) and the specified column indices as the input, to provide me with the p value from each test

Comment: `apply(test, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:5], x[6:10])$p.value)`

Comment: Error in t.test.default(x[1:5], x[6:10]) : not enough 'x' observations  could you help with this error

Comment: How does `str(test)` look like? Does `test <- matrix(sample(1:100,100), nrow = 10); apply(test, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:5], x[6:10])$p.value)` work for you? Then, start look for how *my* `test` differs from *your* `test`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you overwrite `test` all the time. If you really want to use a for loop for this purpose and extract the p-values afterwards, this would better work:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(sample(1:100,100), nrow = 10)

test = list()
a = 0

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  a <- a + 1
  test[[a]] <- t.test(x[i, 1:5], x[i, 6:10])
}

lapply(test, "[[", "p.value")
```

However, using `apply` the way nadizan proposed is much more preferred in this case.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think that in order to use `return` you have to define a function (I am actually surprised you don't get an error). What happens is that the loop performs all the tests as you want but it overwrites them on the same variable `test`, so at the end you have only the last result.</strike>

*Edit:* In fact, I checked and the `return`should let you exit at the first iteration, thus getting only the result of the first test.

One simple way to fix this is to create, for example, a vector and then append each new result in the same position as the correspondent row:

```
test <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    test[i] <- t.test(x[i, 1:5], x[i, 6:10])
}
```

Notice that appending to an empty vector/list is quite expensive as its final length increases, so you may want to initialize it with NAs with the same length as the number of rows of the dataframe:

```
test <- rep (NA,nrow(x))
```